# installing firebase on ionic angular 7 project

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire, angular-standalone-components

I used ng add @angular/fire to add firebase to ionic angular 7 project. When I checked the package.json file I found only @angular/fire without firebase package and rxfire package.
Also creating the ionic app generated standalone version of angular without the app.module.ts

Now I know that I need to add the providers in the component in the imports like

```
provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
provideFirestore(() => getFirestore())
```

but I need to know in which component

Comment: Looking for the answer as well

Comment: See. I did something that worked very well.
first install ionic using the normal way through documentation.
second install ng add @angular/fire
third create new angular project ng new my-app
forth install ng add @ionic/angular
fifth copy the app.module and app-routing.module into your project
sixth remove the standalone property from the default created component (home.Page) and update it in the app-routing.module
seventh copy the code from main.ts to main.ts in your project
(you are copying from the regular angular installation project to the ionic project)
I tested the procedures

Comment: I forget something. In the sixth procedure, remove module imports from default component (home.Page) as well (keep module imports in app.module)
note: when you make the other project install firebase on it using nd add @angular/fire and it will do all the imports for you in app.module

Answer (score 0):

The most reasonable is create app.module.ts and run ng add @angular/fire, after the wizard is finish, insert AppModule into import section in every component need firebase.